# how to add synonym index on lucene

Tags: lucene

I have a synonym table with list of synonyms comma separated. I want Lucene to consider these synonyms also while I indexing a text value. I am using StandardAnalyzer to Index. How can I make Lucene to make use of Synonym as well? Here is my code using StandardAnalyzer

```
FSDirectory fsDircetory = FSDirectory.open(new File("/home/lenovo/index"));
indexwriter = new IndexWriter(fsDircetory,
    new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_31),
    true,IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new Field("title",recipeVO.getTitle(),
    Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));
indexwriter.addDocument(doc);
indexwriter.close()
```